# jQuery UI Droppable not accepted event

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, droppable, jquery-ui-droppable

UI droppable for a project, I would like to detect the opposite to the accepted event.

I mean that if i drag and drop a not accepted container do some action, so far I haven't found any way to detect it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out that using the `revert` option for the **draggable** event can solve it.

```
$("selector").draggable({
    revert : function(droppableContainer) {
            if(droppableContainer) {
                // drop is valid
            }else {
                // drop is invalid
            }
            return(!droppableContainer) //returns the draggable to its original position
        }
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

That works great, thanks. Have just followed up on it a bit below.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Droppable - Default functionality</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {


    //The red div becomes draggable
    $(".red").draggable({
    revert : function(droppableContainer) {
            if(droppableContainer) {
                //If it's droppable : 
                alert('valid');
                $(this).css("visibility", 'hidden');
            }else {
                //if it's not droppable : 
                alert('invalid');
            }
            return(!droppableContainer) //returns the draggable to its original position
        }
   });

    //The pink div becomes draggable
    $(".pink").draggable({
    revert : function(droppableContainer) {
            if(droppableContainer) {
                //If it's droppable : 
                alert('valid');
                $(this).css("visibility", 'hidden');
            }else {
                //if it's not droppable : 
                alert('invalid');
            }
            return(!droppableContainer) //returns the draggable to its original position
        }
   });


    $(".dropdiv").droppable({accept: '.pink',});

    });


  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="ui-widget-content red" style="width: 400px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; float: left; border:3px solid red;">
  <p>Drag</p>
</div>

<div class="ui-widget-content pink" style="width: 400px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; float: left; border:3px solid pink;">
  <p>Drag</p>
</div>

<div class="dropdiv ui-widget-header" style="width: 400px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; float: left; border:3px solid black;">
  <p>Drop here</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please include in the header of your answer what changes you did? It is unclear what was the source of inspiration of your code as well.